# Aspect Ratio Plot Box R

Tags: r, plot, aspect-ratio, axes

So, I'm trying to write a function that will graph a rectangle based on the inputs `xlo`, `xhi`, `ylo`, and `yhi`. (I have other dreams for this function as well, but those seem to be okay despite this being, one would think, the most obvious step.) I want the rectangle to have an aspect ratio of 1, which is okay, but I'd really like the surrounding axes to also have an aspect ratio of 1. I'm trying to give the rectangle a 10% margin all around. I've chosen arbitrary values just to illustrate my point; these should be passed in by the user. My attempt at accomplishing this:

```
xlo = 100
xhi = 700
ylo = 200
yhi = 1000
plot.new()
xmarg = 0.1*(xhi-xlo)
ymarg = 0.1*(yhi-ylo)
my.x.lim = c((xlo - xmarg), (xhi + xmarg))
my.y.lim = c((ylo - ymarg), (yhi + ymarg))
plot(my.x.lim, my.y.lim, type="n", xlab = '', ylab = '', asp = 1)
rect(xlo, ylo, xhi, yhi, lty = 2)
```

As mentioned above, I can make the aspect ratio of the rectangle itself 1, but the axes themselves still look dumb.

[image]

Can anyone help? It would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
xlo = 100
xhi = 700
ylo = 200
yhi = 1000
xmarg = 0.1*(xhi-xlo)
ymarg = 0.1*(yhi-ylo)
my.x.lim = c((xlo - xmarg), (xhi + xmarg))
my.y.lim = c((ylo - ymarg), (yhi + ymarg))

devMin <- min(dev.size('cm'))
whRatio <- (yhi - ylo) / (xhi - xlo)

if(whRatio < 1){
  wid <- devMin
  hei <- wid * whRatio
}else{
  hei <- devMin
  wid <- hei / whRatio
}

layout(matrix(1), widths=lcm(wid), heights=lcm(hei))
par(xaxs='i', yaxs='i')
plot(xlo, ylo, xlim=my.x.lim, ylim=my.y.lim, type="n", xlab = '', ylab = '', asp = 1)
rect(xlo, ylo, xhi, yhi, lty = 2)
```